# Where I can download weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService Class or Jar

Tags: java, weblogic

I need to implement Weblogic singleton service, How to load   weblogic.cluster.singleton.SingletonService class?

Comment: Please give me the Link??

Comment: Brother. I am asking the exact website. I searched on the google, but I could not find it.

Comment: brother, did you get the Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class can be found in this library : $MW_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-classes.jar
Documentation : 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24391/weblogic/cluster/singleton/SingletonService.html

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLJCA/CLUST/service_migration.htm#CLUST377

Comment: hi.. It is API Doc. I need Jar File

Comment: The class can be found in this library : $MW_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-classes.jar in your weblogic server installation folder.

Comment: Not found in the loctation

Comment: Which weblogic server version did you install ?

Comment: Oracle Internet Application Server 10g & Weblogic 12c (12.2.1)

Comment: $MW_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/wls-api.jar

Comment: Brother. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of weblogic 12.2.1.2.0 this class is in two jar.
$MW_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/wls-api-part.jar
$MW_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/wls-api.jar

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague as it doesn't give any clues about your build technology, but for a maven project I use a windows batch script to install the maven dependencies into the local `%USERPROFILE%\.m2` repository as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/config_maven.htm#MAVEN8853

You would need to modify it to point at your own Java and WebLogic install locations.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set JAVA_HOME=D:\jdk8
set WLS_HOME=D:\WebLogic
set M2_HOME=%WLS_HOME%\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.maven_3.2.5
set MVN=%M2_HOME%\bin\mvn
cd /d %WLS_HOME%\oracle_common\plugins\maven\com\oracle\maven\oracle-maven-sync\12.2.1
call %mvn% install:install-file -DpomFile=oracle-maven-sync-12.2.1.pom -Dfile=oracle-maven-sync-12.2.1.jar
cd /d %WLS_HOME%\
call %mvn% com.oracle.maven:oracle-maven-sync:push -Doracle-maven-sync.oracleHome=%WLS_HOME%\
call %mvn% help:describe -DgroupId=com.oracle.weblogic -DartifactId=weblogic-maven-plugin -Dversion=12.2.1-2-0
mvn archetype:crawl -Dcatalog=%USERPROFILE%/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml
```

Then in your pom.xml you can reference weblogic classes.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-2-0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```